# Pumpkin-Eating festival/Pumpkin-Eating Festival

Tags: hyphenation

Do I have to hyphenate the last word of this phrase, which is the name of a festival? I do know that the first word, which is a compound adjective, is certainly hyphenated, but about the word *festival* itself, I am in doubt.

1. I'm now going to take part in Pumpkin-Eating festival.
2. I'm now going to take part in Pumpkin-Eating Festival.

Comment: Hyphenate or capitalize?

Comment: Let me clue you in to something. There are all sorts of pumpkin festivals, eating them, not so much. In any event, you need an a or a the.

Comment: Beware the pumpkin-eating festival: close your garden gates.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to capitalize it, unless the event itself is *called* 'The Pumpkin-Eating Festival.' In any other case, you'd refer to it as 'pumkin-eating festival.'

To elaborate,

there are a few ways you could put this, and you need to offer a little more context- specifically, by introducing articles.

Let's say that the person you're talking to doesn't know about these sorts of events, or that they don't know about the fact that you do these sorts of things. You'd use the article *a*, and it would look something like this:

> I'm now going to take part in **a** pumpkin-eating festival.

Another possibility is that there's only one event that entails eating pumpkins that you could possibly be referring to. Perhaps it's a big local thing, or there's any other reason that both you and your listener know about it. In this situation, you'd use the article *the*, and you-again- wouldn't capitalize it.

> I'm now going to take part in **the** pumpkin-eating festival.

(I'm also curious about your usage of *now*, which implies that you've participated in many different food-eating festivals, the next of which is going to be one with pumpkins. If this isn't the case, I'd recommend cutting it.)

The only case in which you *would* capitalize it, you'd capitalize everything. This would be if the event was literally called 'The Pumpkin-Eating Festival.' (Not a great name- Gorge on Gourds, or actually anything else, would be a better name.)  You would use the article *the*, and it would look like this:

> I'm now going to be taking part in **the** Pumpkin-Eating Festival.

There's never going to be any situation in which you only capitalize part of it.

Oh, and best of luck!

Comment: We always use *the* when it comes to festivals, right?

Comment: it's a good rule of thumb, yes